# How to remove curly brackets in Postgres when querying XML data with XPath

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

In the Postgres documentation you will find an example for how to use XPath to query stored xml data. Here is the example for the XPath query:

```
SELECT xpath('/my:a/text()', '<my:a xmlns:my="http://example.com">test</my:a>',
             ARRAY[ARRAY['my', 'http://example.com']]);

 xpath  
--------
 {test}
```

As you can see the result is returned with curly brackets. Or if the query would result in a list, it could look like this: {"Pens 10 piece",Folder,"Copy Paper",Laptop}.

How can I have the result without the brackets? Or in another format so that it is easier to use in JavaScript/Node.

Comment: Are you sure the brackets are part of the result ? I suppose that's how PostgreSQL display the values contained in an array. What's in the output if you use `array_to_string` function ?

Comment: Yes, if you run above query you will see the result in pgAdmin with the brackets. Later when I do the query in Nodejs, then I get the result also with the brackets. 

Your `array_to_string`  didn't work but it pointed me into the right direction. After some more searching I think I understand that the result of that query is an array and that's why it is being displayed with the brackets. If the XPath query result is just one value like above, then I managed to cast it by wrapping the query in `(xpath....)[1]::text`. With this addition the result is now displayed without the brackets.

Comment: If the query comes back with multiple values, then the result would be something like this: `{"value 1", "value 2", "value 3"}`. The result in Nodejs(with the 'pg' module) would be: `"{\"value 1\",\"value 2\",\"value 3\"}"`
Therefore it looks like I would either need to find a way to return the values from Postgres without the "\" or do the formatting in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution in this case was:

**The query results in one value**
Wrap the query with `()[1]::text`

**The query results in multiple values**
Wrap the query with `array_to_json()`

Comment: Nice. It could be useful later. Good job.